# FireWatir TextField set : Very Slow

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

When calling the `set` method of a text_field in ruby, the text is being entered at a very slow rate in the browser, roughly at 1 character / second.

Environment Information:

1. Ubuntu 10.10
2. FireFox 3.6.13
3. JSSh 0.9
4. Ruby 1.9.2p136
5. FireWatir 1.7.1

Kindly advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in FireWatir that you might want to take to the developers.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug: [WTR-397](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/WTR-397)

Workaround is to use [watir-webdriver](http://zeljkofilipin.com/2010/01/12/watir-on-webdriver/) or to use `value=` instead of `set`. Example:

```
browser.text_field(how => what).value= "string"
```

Answer (score 0):

solve slow key type issue on firewatir:

need to edit the file `text_field.rb`
enter to the folder

1. `#>cd /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.7.1/lib/firewatir/elements/` make it writeable
2. `#>chmod 777 text_field.rb` edit the proc `def doKeyPress( value )`
3. put # in front of `@o.fireEvent("onKeyDown")` and `@o.fireEvent("onKeyPress")` and `@o.fireEvent("onKeyPress")`

instead enter `fire_key_events`

```
 def doKeyPress( value )
      begin
        max = maxlength
        if (max > 0 && value.length > max)
          original_value = value
          value = original_value[0...max]
          element.log " Supplied string is #{suppliedValue.length} chars, which exceeds the max length (#{max}) of the field. Using value: #{value}"
        end
      rescue
        # probably a text area - so it doesnt have a max Length
      end
      for i in 0..value.length-1
        #sleep element.typingspeed   # typing speed
        c = value[i,1]
        #element.log  " adding c.chr " + c  #.chr.to_s
        @o.value = "#{(@o.value.to_s + c)}"   #c.chr
    fire_key_events #add this
        #@o.fireEvent("onKeyDown")
        #@o.fireEvent("onKeyPress")
        #@o.fireEvent("onKeyUp")
      end
```

now it should work faster