# Watir Checkbox marking slow with Firefox on Linux

Tags: firefox, checkbox, watir, firewatir, performance

I am running Watir on a Linux machine for testing with Firefox 3.6. I have observed that marking multiple checkboxes is quite slow. I have implemented the fix for a related problem with text boxes, using .value instead of .set.  See [Firewatir Textfield Set Very Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000164/firewatir-textfield-set-very-slow)

However, I cannot find a way to speed up checkboxes. There is no value method for checkboxes. The second solution for text boxes that alters the event handlers is intriguing. My question is how do I find the right file to edit for Ruby 1.9.2 and Firewatir, and what would I change?  Thanks.

Ruby code:

```
checkBoxFlag = false
prevBlogCountLabel = @browser.span(:class, 'linksnumber').text
begin
   @browser.checkbox(:value, blogid).set(set_or_clear=true)
   checkBoxFlag = true
rescue
   # unable to check box - does not exist
   checkBoxFlag = false
end
```

And here is the relevant HTML snippet:

```
<table id="bloglist">
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td>
<input class="shiftselect" type="checkbox" value="966393" name="id[]">
</td>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML and Watir code.

Comment: I'd give serious consideration to moving to a current version of firefox and watir-webdriver.  at the very least try a small portion of your script in that environment and see if it's any better performance wise.   Firewatir is getting zero development effort at this point, and firefox 3.6 usage is waning with more users having moved to a more recent version

Comment: I started out with the current version of Firefox and what I thought was the latest Watir code for FF, Firewatir. That was a complete disaster. The target web site didn't work at all with that combination. I settled on FF 3.6 and Firewatir because that was the only thing that worked. I'd be willing to try again. What is the definitive source for the 'latest' tools to use? I've seen many tutorials that recommend many different combinations.

Comment: You want Watir-Webdriver, it has replaced Firewatir, chromewatir, and operawatir.   Firewatir was basically rendered obsolete when Firefox removed jssh starting with version 4.   Watir-webdriver gives you the friendly watir API but uses Webdriver (from  the selenium project) to give you cross browser support

Comment: Thanks @ChuckvanderLinden, I found the instructions in the Watir book at [link](http://watir.com/installation/).

Answer (score 0):

Try "value" instead of "set" function
`value("checked")` maybe

Comment: Here's the relevant Ruby code:      checkBoxFlag = false
     prevBlogCountLabel = @browser.span(:class, 'linksnumber').text
     begin
        @browser.checkbox(:value, blogid).set(set_or_clear=true)
        checkBoxFlag = true
     rescue
        # unable to check box - does not exist
        checkBoxFlag = false
     end

Comment: Tried value instead of set - `@browser.checkbox(:value, blogid).value("checked")` - does not check any checkboxes