# How can I manage slow textarea speed with Watir-Webdriver in Firefox, linux?

Tags: performance, firefox, selenium, webdriver, watir

I am using 
Ruby 1.8.7, Watir-Webdriver 0.6.1, Arch Linux, Firefox 14

I have read a lot of answers and examples in this topic, but none of them worked for me.
When I want to paste a large piece of data (only about 15 lines of text) into a textarea it is terrible slow. As I don't want typing emulation, I would like the maximum available speed, so I tried to set the variable "browser.speed = :zippy" but it seems don't work in Watir-Webdriver, only an error message appears: "undefined method `speed=' for #"

Then I tried to set native_events to false, an error message arises again: 
"undefined method `native_events' for #"
so I am a bit confused.

This is my whole code snippet

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'xmlsimple'
default_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default"
default_profile.native_events = false
default_profile['javascript.enabled']=false
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff, :profile => default_profile
browser.speed = :zippy
```

line 5. and 6. and 8. all throw an error message.

At last I tried to edit text_field.rb as it is mentioned in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000164/firewatir-textfield-set-very-slow) but it is in a .gem file and in a tar.gz. I unzipped but I am unable to find the relevant lines:

```
# encoding: utf-8
module Watir
  class TextField < Input
    include UserEditable

    attributes Watir::TextArea.typed_attributes
    remove_method :type # we want Input#type here, which was overriden by TextArea's attributes

    private

    def locator_class
      TextFieldLocator
    end

    def selector_string
      selector = @selector.dup
      selector[:type] = '(any text type)'
      selector[:tag_name] = "input or textarea"
      selector.inspect
    end
  end

  module Container
    def text_field(*args)
      TextField.new(self, extract_selector(args).merge(:tag_name => "input"))
    end

    def text_fields(*args)
      TextFieldCollection.new(self, extract_selector(args).merge(:tag_name => "input"))
    end
  end # Container

  class TextFieldCollection < InputCollection
    private

    def locator_class
      TextFieldLocator
    end

    def element_class
      TextField
    end
  end # TextFieldCollection
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For large strings, I would recommend getting the text into the system clipboard and then paste into the text field.

On OS X, the `pbcopy` command line utility can be used for this:

```
  IO.popen("pbcopy", "w") { |io| io << long_string }
  browser.text_field.send_keys([:command, 'v'])
```

I'm sure there are Linux equivalents that work equally well (and you would need to use `[:control, 'v']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run IE with watir-webdriver. I managed to make it run a little faster by editing the \Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\watir-webdriver-0.6.2\lib\watir-webdriver\browser.rb file and add this, before the def initialize(browser = :firefox, *args):

```
# Run fast
$FAST_SPEED = ARGV.delete('-f')

 @@speed = $FAST_SPEED ? :fast : :slow
    def self.speed
      return :fast if $FAST_SPEED
      @@speed
    end
    def self.speed= x
      $FAST_SPEED = nil
      @@speed = x
    end




    def initialize_options

      self.speed = browser.speed

      @ole_object = nil
      @page_container = self
      @error_checkers = []

      @url_list = []
    end

     def speed= how_fast
      case how_fast
      when :zippy then
        @typingspeed = 0
        @pause_after_wait = 0.01
        @type_keys = false
        @speed = :fast
      when :fast then
        @typingspeed = 0
        @pause_after_wait = 0.01
        @type_keys = true
        @speed = :fast
      when :slow then
        @typingspeed = 0.08
        @pause_after_wait = 0.1
        @type_keys = true
        @speed = :slow
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "Invalid speed: #{how_fast}"
      end
    end

    def speed
      return @speed if @speed == :slow
      return @type_keys ? :fast : :zippy
    end

    # deprecated: use speed = :fast instead
    def set_fast_speed
      self.speed = :fast
    end

    # deprecated: use speed = :slow instead    
    def set_slow_speed
      self.speed = :slow
    end
```

After that I modified def goto(uri) with:

```
def goto(uri)
  uri = "http://#{uri}" unless uri =~ URI.regexp

  @driver.navigate.to uri
  run_checkers
  initialize_options

  url
end
```

It works a little faster, and I don't know if it is the best solution, as I just started with watir.

Hope it helps.